# Add CRON via shell to run Python

Tags: python, shell, cron, debian

My cron doesn't seem to execute every 5 mins. Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong?

I made it executable using this command:

```
chmod +x /etc/utilities/poll.py
```

I can run it manually with this command:

```
cd /etc/utilities
python poll.py
```

When I run it like this I get an error:

```
root@li453-78:~# /etc/utilities/poll.py                                                                                                                              
-bash: /etc/utilities/poll.py: Permission denied
```

This is the command I use to add it to shell (via my automatic deployment script):

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "*/5 * * * * /etc/utilities/poll.py"; } | crontab -
```

The start of my python file is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

So, could someone please enlighten me about how I should be adding the cron to my debian server via shell so that it executes?

Comment: Sorry to ask the trivial. Did you chmod ``poll.py`` to makes it executable ? Make sure that is it executable for the user which runs the crontab.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just edited my question actually to include that, so the answer is, "I believe so"

Comment: Then why the permission denied ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python` shouldn't be `/usr/bin/env**/**python`?

Comment: And yet you don't seem to have permissions to execute it. What does `ls -l /etc/utilities/poll.py` say ?

Comment: It says this: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10082 Jul 24 16:00 /etc/utilities/poll.py

Comment: It seems that my automated script didn't make it executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the help from here, for whatever reason, even though I had the code correct to make the script executable, this line didn't seem to fire in my deployment script, meaning that all I had to do was run it afterwards to make it executable and then everything worked.

**Lesson learnt:** If you need to do this, the code above works